# sfdcIFrameOrigin parameter being added to Site url unnecessarily when using mobile

Tags: visualforce, lightning, force.com-sites, dynamic-visualforce, urlrewriter

I have a Visualforce Page which is hosted on a Salesforce site. I am using a URL rewriter to make the URL into a friendly one. The page has a few parameters being passed into it (3 to be exact) and the URL rewriter takes those parameters and converts it into the following format:

" *https://domain-name/page-name/parameter1/parameter2/parameter3/* ".

Everything works fine on the Desktop, but on mobile browsers, a new parameter gets appended to the URL - sfdcIFrameOrigin. The new URL comes as:

" *https://domain-name/page-name/parameter1/parameter2/parameter3/?sfdcIFrameOrigin=null* " .

Has anyone else faced this issue? I am not sure where this parameter comes from and would like to remove it. I tried a Javascript approach to remove the parameter once the page loads but it then reloads the page and that creates an unfriendly user experience. Does anyone have any better suggestions?

Comment: I got the same error

Answer (score 1):

I could not find any documentation to back this, but it looks like it is added by Salesforce to distinguish between Classic and Lightning experience.

Reference: http://forceguru.blogspot.com/2016/09/lightning-experience-or-classic-view.html